# Webview navigation url is wrong in IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a sample application in Xamarin.form, which use to showing local HTML content in webview.

I want to use the navigation event to change the content of webview.

It working fine in Android but in IOS not getting navigation URL.
In IOS navigation getting the full path of IOS application like...

```
 file://locationpathofIOSapplication/WorkingWithWebviewiOS.app
```

```
public class LocalHtml : ContentPage
{
    public LocalHtml()
    {
        var browser = new WebView();
        var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        htmlSource.Html = @"<html><body>
                            <h1 onclick=""window.location='Navigation://yahoo'"">Xamarin.Forms</h1>
                            </br> </br></br>
                            <a href=""Navigation://google""> Click on me</a>
                            </br> </br></br>
                            <p>Welcome to WebView Test Navigation.</p>
                            </body>
                            </html>";
        browser.Source = htmlSource;
        Content = browser;
        browser.Navigated += Browser_Navigated;
    }

    private void Browser_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = e.Url;
        if(url == "google")
        {
            //do some action
        }
        else if(url == "yahoo")
        {
            //do some action
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom renderer to get the navigation URL in IOS:

In xamarin.forms, use  MessagingCenter to Subscribe the url:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        var browser = new myWebView();
        var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        htmlSource.Html = @"<html><body>
                        <h1 onclick=""window.location='Navigation://yahoo'"">Xamarin.Forms</h1>
                        </br> </br></br>
                        <a href=""Navigation://google""> Click on me</a>
                        </br> </br></br>
                        <p>Welcome to WebView Test Navigation.</p>
                        </body>
                        </html>";
        browser.Source = htmlSource;
        Content = browser;
        browser.Navigated += Browser_Navigated;


        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object,string>(this, "shouldLoadUrl", (sender, arg) => {
            // do something whenever the "shouldLoadUrl" message is sent

            //arg is the url 
            Console.WriteLine(arg);

            myAction(arg);
        });

    }

    private void Browser_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = e.Url;

        if (url.StartsWith("file:"))
        {
            return;
        }

        myAction(url);
    }

    public void myAction(string url) {

        if (url == "google")
        {
            //do some action
        }
        else if (url == "yahoo")
        {
            //do some action
        }
    }
}

public class myWebView : WebView {

}
```

In the iOS project, get the url string in `ShouldStartLoad` method and handle your logic there:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(myWebView), typeof(myWebRender))]

namespace App452.iOS
{
    class myWebRender :  WebViewRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {   // perform initial setup
                UIWebView myWebView = (UIWebView)this.NativeView;

                myWebView.Delegate = new CustomWebViewDelegate();             
            }
        }

        public class CustomWebViewDelegate : UIWebViewDelegate
        {
            public CustomWebViewDelegate()
            {
            }

            public override bool ShouldStartLoad(UIWebView webView, NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(request.Url.AbsoluteString);
                //Handle your logic here

                MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(new Object(), "shouldLoadUrl",request.Url.AbsoluteString);
                return true.
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error after use delegate  {Foundation.You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method: Exception of type 'Foundation.You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method' was thrown.

Comment: @user619 Remove the line `return base.ShouldStartLoad(webView, request, navigationType);` and return true/false depending on your own situation.

Comment: but also getting full URL in field request.Url.AbsoluteString.

Comment: @user619 I just test, when you click the "Click on me", you will get the url. When you first load the page, you will get the full path. Right?  That's what you want  when you click the "Click on me"?

Comment: yes, you are right, I got the URL, but how can get this URL in PCL "Browser_Navigated" event.

Comment: @user619 Use a messageCenter would work, see my edited answer.